# If inside select clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume I have following SQL `select` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table_1 t1
  join some_table t2 on t2.some_id =  t1.id and
  t2.school_id = 56 and
  t1.is_valid = 1 and 
  t2.status in (15, 16, 17, 18);
```

But I have also to check, if `t2.status = 18`, then I have also to check if `t2.date < 01.01.2015`

How can I add this condition to this `select`?

Comment: What do you want to _do_ in those cases?  I can't tell if you want a `WHERE` clause or a `CASE` statement.

Comment: AND (t2.date < 01.01.2015 OR t2.status <> 18)

Comment: Whats the point for putting `18` in the `IN` clause ?

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example. Please show us the complete stored procedure.

Comment: @Bob Do you want `t2.status=18` as a condition or do you want to implement `t2.date < 01.01.2015` (this) filter only when it fulfills first condition ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only want to join on rows that have a status of 18 when the date (which is a bad name for a column, since it's an Oracle reserved word. I'm also going to assume it's of DATE datatype) is less than 1st Jan 2015. If so, then the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table_1 t1
       join some_table t2 on t2.some_id =  t1.id 
                             and t2.school_id = 56
                             and t1.is_valid = 1
                             and (t2.status in (15, 16, 17)
                                  or (t2.status = 18 and t2.date < to_date('01.01.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy.')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `or` checking for 'not 18', or matching your second condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table_1 t1
join   some_table t2
on     t2.some_id = t1.id
and    t2.school_id = 56
and    t1.is_valid = 1
and    t2.status in (15, 16, 17, 18)
/* added part */
where  ( t2.status != 18
         or t2.date < to_date('01.01.2015', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
       )
```

Comment: @CoderofCode: If you don't have it, it will leave out the lines having `status = 18`...

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
where t2.status <> 18 or t2.date < date '2015-01-01'
```